# Russian Characters are appearing as ??? in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, utf-8

So I have created a controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    @ResponseBody
    public String display()
    {
        return "Мегафон Игры";  //russian characters
    }   
}
```

Now when i hit the url http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/hello/all 
I am getting `??????? ????` in the response.

I have configured URIEncoding in server.xml file of tomcat something like this

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>` 
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

I have tested my response on Chrome browser,postman and eclipse console.

I have even tried adding encoding-filter in web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>FALSE</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Please help me what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be that you need to define the encoding of the response body.
For that you can use the `@RequestMapping` annotation, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(
     value = "/all", 
     method = RequestMethod.GET,
     produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)
```

Comment: @ShubhamChopra Awesome! Btw, I thought I went back in time hahaha Did you delete the old comment?

Comment: I don't know, i never deleted somehow it was not there, so I thought to add it back,

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the source encoding while building your project ?

Comment: This should likely be a comment.

Comment: i have added
 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
in pom.xml